# How does c3p0's JdbcProxyGenerator work (metaprogramming in Java‽)?

Tags: c3p0

I've been using c3p0 with hibernate for a couple of years.  When looking at exception stack traces, I see classes such as `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement` in the stack.  I went looking for the source code for these classes and came across the curous `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.codegen` package.

In particular, it looks like [JdbcProxyGenerator](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/c3p0/c3p0/0.9.1.2/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/codegen/JdbcProxyGenerator.java) is metaprogramming in Java.  I'm having a hard time understanding the codegen mechanism and why it is used.  The built jar contains these generated classes, so I'm assuming these classes are built during the build, perhaps as part of a two-phase build.  The codegen package does not appear to be in the generated jar.

Any insight would be appreciated, just for my own curiosity.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you are absolutely right.

c3p0 uses code generation to generate non reflective proxy implementations of large JDBC interfaces, "java bean" classes with lots of properties, and some classes containing debug and logging flags (to set up conditional compilation within the build).

You can always see the generated classes by typing ant codegen in the source distribution, and then looking at the build/codebase directory. The latest binary distribution of c3p0 (0.9.2-pre2) includes the generated sources in a src.jar file, which you can also find as a maven artifact at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mchange/c3p0/0.9.2-pre2-RELEASE/c3p0-0.9.2-pre2-RELEASE-sources.jar

I hope this helps!

---

Comment: Thanks Steve, that makes sense.  I appreciate all your work on c3p0!